# How can I convert my working SQL query to Linq (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a working SQL query that returns the results I want on SQL Server:

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(CriticalCount) As CriticalCount,
  SUM(HighCount) As HighCount,
  SUM(MediumCount) As MediumCount,
  SUM(LowCount) As LowCount,
  Timestamp
FROM [dbo].[TicketCounts]
GROUP BY Timestamp
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
```

The result set is:

| CriticalCount | HighCount | MediumCount | LowCount | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 15 | 18 | 3 | 2021-07-01 11:00:00 |
| 24 | 10 | 42 | 15 | 2021-06-30 10:00:00 |

In my `TicketCountRepository` of my .Net Core 5.0 project, I want this method to return the same results:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<TicketCount>> GetTicketCounts()
{
  return await _dbContext.TicketCounts
      .GroupBy(o => o.Timestamp)
      .Select(tc => new TicketCount
      {
        CriticalCount = tc.Sum(o => o.CriticalCount),
        HighCount = tc.Sum(o => o.HighCount),
        MediumCount = tc.Sum(o => o.MediumCount),
        LowCount = tc.Sum(o => LowCount)
      }).OrderByDescending(o => o.Timestamp).toListAsync();
}
```

The code compiles fine, but when I hit this method in the `TicketCount` controller, I get a 500 error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression DbSet().GroupBy(keySelector: o => o.Timestamp, elementSelector o => o).Select(e => new TicketCount { CriticalCount = e.Sum(s => s.CriticalCount), HighCount = e.Sum(s => s.HighCount), MediumCount = e.Sum(s => s.MediumCount), LowCount = e.Sum(s => s.LowCount)}).OrderByDescending(e0 => e0.Timestamp) could not be translated.  Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList' or 'ToListAsync'.

What am I doing wrong?  Should I use something other than linq to get the result set needed?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the Linq you show here. Can you shoe the exact error message? What database provider are you using?

Comment: Check the SQL Server log files.  The 500 error indicates that the server got error during processing of query.

Comment: @DavidG, I added more details from the error log

Comment: @jdweng What?! 500 error has nothing to do with SQL Server logs. Sometimes I feel like you're a poorly written AI just writing random comments.

Comment: @ews2001 you forgot to add `Timestamp` in the `Select` clause. In the `OrderBy`, `o` is really the `TicketCount` object, which has no value. Add `TicketCount=tc.Key`

Comment: Thank you Serge and Jamie Ide!  You both had the right answer, thanks so much for pointing out adding Timestamp to my select clause, it's working correctly now.  Since Serge answered first, I'll award him the points.

Comment: @DavidG : Isn't the error a HTTP Error "500 Internal Server Error" indicating the error occurred while the server was processing query and wouldn't those errors be reported in the SQL Server logs?

Comment: @jdweng No, the 500 errors wouldn't be anywhere near the SQL logs. In fact, SQL Server wouldn't even receive a connection because the query couldn't be generated.

Comment: @DavidG : You are assuming the error is in Net and not in the Server.

Comment: @jdweng No I'm not, I'm looking directly at the error message given above that shows exactly where the error is.

Comment: @DavidG : That is were the query is sent to the server.  Serge answer is fixing a syntax error that was caught in the server.  Checking the Server logs would of shown the error.

Comment: @jdweng No it isn't, it's where the expressions are pulled apart to generate the SQL. If it can't make a SQL statement, how can it possibly talk to SQL Server when it doesn't know what to send yet? Take this from someone who has contributed to the EF codebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't select timestamp move it before select

```
return await _dbContext.TicketCounts
      .GroupBy(o => o.Timestamp)
       .OrderByDescending(o => o.Timestamp)
      .Select(tc => new TicketCount
      {
        CriticalCount = tc.Sum(o => o.CriticalCount),
        HighCount = tc.Sum(o => o.HighCount),
        MediumCount = tc.Sum(o => o.MediumCount),
        LowCount = tc.Sum(o => LowCount)
      }).ToListAsync();
```

or  you can try to add Timestamp property to TicketCount and add it to Select.

Answer (score 5):

The type you're querying is wrong, it's the return type instead of the type containing the raw data. You want something like:

```
  return await _dbContext.Tickets
  .GroupBy(o => o.Timestamp)
  .Select(x => new TicketCount
  {
    Timestamp = x.Key,
    CriticalCount = x.Sum(o => o.CriticalCount),
    HighCount = x.Sum(o => o.HighCount),
    MediumCount = x.Sum(o => o.MediumCount),
    LowCount = x.Sum(o => LowCount)
  }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp).toListAsync();
```